# ejabberdctl command inside a script gives error "Connection attempt from disallowed node"

Tags: linux, bash, debian, ejabberd

I'm running ejabberd-14.12 on a Debian 7.6 server, single node.

I've installed ejabberd with the interactive .run package.

I've started ejabberd (logged as root) with:

```
# /opt/ejabberd-14.12/bin/ejabberdctl start
```

The log tells that:

```
ejabberd_app:start:69 ejabberd 14.12 is started in the node ejabberd@localhost
```

Then, I can see the erlang cookie in my /root directory:

```
-r-------- 1 root     root       20 ago  9 00:00 .erlang.cookie
```

If I try to create a user in command line mode, everything is ok:

```
# /opt/ejabberd-14.12/bin/ejabberdctl register foo myhost.lchat.local foopwd
```

And the user is created (I can see it on the web gui).

If the same command is embedded inside a .sh script (with the full command path), and launched by a daemon (owned by root), it generates an error in the ejabberd error.log:

```
[error] <0.435.0> ** Connection attempt from disallowed node 'ctl-ejabberd@localhost' **
```

I believe that it's a security issue, in order to avoid commands from unauthorized users.

What can I do to have the command accepted also from script ?

Answer (score 0):

The error means the environment is not using the same cookie for connecting from the `command` Erlang node to the primary ejabberd node.

I guess the script run as another user (despite being own by root). The user that will run the script need to have the same `.erlang.cookie` file in its home directory.

Note: you should not run a server as root, ejabberd or any other type of network server. This is against security best practices.

Comment: Thank you Mickaël. At the end, I restart from scratch,  and installed the Deb package (before I've used the .run installer). With the Deb package the script works as expected, and I resolved my needs. But now the .erlang.cookie has disappeared. It may be because now I have an ejabberd system user (that in .run installer were not created).